# evt.target.result is empty?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, filereader

For some reason, in the following code, `evt.target.result` is empty. Why is that?

```
function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var file = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];

    handleFiles(file, evt.target);
}

function handleFiles(file, target) {
    loadSongAnimate();

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // init the reader event handlers
    reader.onloadend = handleReaderLoadEnd;

    // begin the read operation
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function handleReaderLoadEnd(evt) {
    alert('Passing this: ' + evt.target.result);
    document.getElementById('audioTagId').src = evt.target.result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Mortensen. I get the hint, and will follow it in future... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was editing and viewing the file over a local file:// protocol. When you are referencing a local file inside another local file, the blank headers in the referenced local file with throw security errors.

Lesson learned... always upload to a server for testing as well. Would have saved me hours of Googling, and lots of hair.

Comment: You should have accepted mu's answer here, not your own.

Answer (score 8):

From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Event_handlers):

> `onloadend`
>   Called when the read is completed, whether successful or not. This is called after either `onload` or `onerror`.

I suspect that you have an error condition. Add an `onerror` callback and have a look at what `reader.error` has to say. You might want to use separate `onerror`, `onabort`, and `onload` callbacks instead of `onloadend`:

> `onabort`
>   Called when the read operation is aborted.
>
> `onerror`
>   Called when an error occurs.
>
> `onload`
>   Called when the read operation is successfully completed.

That might make it easier to handle the individual events.

---

In your comment you say that you're getting an "error 2", from the [other fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError):

> **Constant**: `SECURITY_ERR`
>   **Value**: 2
>   **Description**: The file could not be accessed for security reasons.

So it looks like you getting a "permission denied" error.

Comment: OK, I am getting an error code "2". This seems to be a generic catch-all error code, so I don't know how I can really troubleshoot it... any ideas on where to look from here?

Comment: @Crossdiver: Looks like you're getting "permission denied" (essentially), I've added a little update to that effect (and added a link that I forgot before).

Comment: @Crossdiver Thanks for the helpful debugging info. For the record, I was repeatedly getting SECURITY_ERR because I was viewing my html locally over file:// and not over http. Lesson learned!

Comment: Yes, that was my problem in the end as well... just because I was viewing the file locally, I would get this Security Error #2. Good to know!!